# What kind of Syngonium species or cultivar this plant is?

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors, aroid

I have a *Syngonium* or commonly known as *Arrowhead vine* but I cannot really decide which species or cultivar it is.

Based on its coloration and texture it looks like a *Syngonium White Butterfly* but by the leaf shape it looks like something else. I have an actual *Syngonium White Butterfly* which is even larger than this one. The main differences:

- On the plant in question the leaves are much narrower and elongated. Even the very young ones at the bottom that were propagated form leafless cuttings. My *White Butterfly* has definitely wider leaves.
- These leaves has very noticeable lobes.

PlantNet app could not tell for sure, it says it is either one of these:

- *Syngonium auritum*
- *Syngonium podophyllum* (White Butterfly)

Could it be simply a mature *Syngonium podophyllum* although the young leaves seem to be different as well. Does anyone have any idea what plant it can be?

---

Here are some pictures.

1. Full plant
   [image: Full plant.]
2. Close-up on newest leaf. Notice the overlapping lobes.
   [image: Close-up on newest leaf.]
3. Another close-up.
   [image]
4. Oldest leaf in dark green with large lobes.
   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The narrower leaved forms of *Syngonium* usually have the two extended points at the base of the leaves, which suggests yours is one of those. The trouble is, this plant has been intensively bred, so that now there are hundreds of different varieties - some have really narrow leaves, others just narrower than usual like yours. You could just Google 'narrow leaved Syngonium', select images and scroll through the many images available on line. I did find a couple with similar leaf shapes, but not the same coloration, but if you have the patience, you may be able to find one that's exactly like yours.